# How to unschedule/reschedule Batch apex which is scheduled via UI?

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I have a batch apex in my Org. which runs every night. I scheduled it via User Interface. Now I want to re-schedule it via UI. How do I do that?

Comment: Delete the old job and schedule anew...

Comment: Oh Silly me. I got it. Go to Scheduled Jobs and Click Manage to delete or reschedule it. Thanks Adrian!